# How can I create and store the path or URL of the QR code image in your database for each product?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, qr-code

I am doing a Laravel project, creating a feature for scanning the QR codes of each product to retrieve product details. My flow is to:

1. Generate 'product_code'(QR code) - using *Milon/Barcode*
2. Associate QR codes with products - store the path or URL of the QR code image in your database for each product.
3. Scan QR code - using *Instascan.Scanner*
4. Retrieve product details - extract the product_code from the scanned content. Then, send an AJAX request to your backend server with the product code.
5. Query Database
6. Return Product Details once the product details are retrieved from database, return them as a response to the frontend.

Currently, I can generate QR codes with the code below:

In ProductController:

```
public function ProductStore(Request $request){
        
        // Generate the product code
        $product_code = uniqid();

        // Generate PNG path for the QR code
        $qrCodePath = DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($product_code, 'QRCODE');

        Product::insert([

            //insert data into product table
            'name' => $request->name,
            'supplier_id' => $request->supplier_id,
            'unit_id' => $request->unit_id,
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'quantity' => '0',
            'product_code' => $qrCodePath,  // Save QR code data
            'created_by' => Auth::user()->id,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 
        ]);

            
        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Product Inserted Successfully', 
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        );

        return redirect()->route('product.all')->with($notification); 

    } // End Method
```

In view:

```
@foreach($product as $key => $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item['supplier']['name'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item['unit']['name'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item['category']['name'] }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <!-- Link to download the QR code image -->
                                <a href="{{ DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($item->product_code, 'QRCODE') }}" download="{{ $item->product_code }}">
                                    <!-- QR code image -->
                                    <img src="{{ DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($item->product_code, 'QRCODE') }}" alt="QR Code" width="100" height="100" />
                                    <br>p - {{ $item -> product_code }}
                                </a>
                            </td>
```

In the database (MySQL), the product_code will be saved in this string format (example: '\65cc0051d5c4bqrcode.png').

**How can I create and store the path or URL of the QR code image in your database for each product**? I need these steps to retrieve product details by sending an AJAX request to the backend server.

Sorry if it's a stupid question. I am new to Laravel.

Comment: In your `Product::insert` aren't you inserting what you need under `product_code' => $qrCodePath` ?

Comment: QR codes represent text. Often that text is a URL, because then people can scan the URL and click it. You appear to be generating a random string with `uniqid`. Is there any reason you can’t just store the URL to the product?

Comment: You don't need to save the qrCode images, there are packages to generate them on the fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all start here and what misled you is the comment:

```
// Generate PNG path for the QR code
$qrCodePath = DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($product_code, 'QRCODE');
```

the above method do the following:

```
//Generate a PNG file that contains the QR code and return the file path
```

so if you put $quCodePath inside product_code field you will override (lose) your product_code with a string containing the file path to your png.

what you can do is

**1) create your qr code at runtime from your product_code:**

```
public function ProductStore(Request $request){
  
  // Generate the product code
  $product_code = uniqid();

  //##################### REMOVE THIS ################################
  // Generate PNG path for the QR code                              ##
  //$qrCodePath = DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($product_code, 'QRCODE');##
  //##################### REMOVE THIS ################################

  Product::insert([

    //insert data into product table
    'name' => $request->name,
    'supplier_id' => $request->supplier_id,
    'unit_id' => $request->unit_id,
    'category_id' => $request->category_id,
    'quantity' => '0',
    'product_code' => $product_code,  // SAVE CODE NOT QR CODE.
    'created_by' => Auth::user()->id,
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 
  ]);

      
  $notification = array(
    'message' => 'Product Inserted Successfully', 
    'alert-type' => 'success'
  );

  return redirect()->route('product.all')->with($notification); 

} // End Method 


/*
<!-- and in view all remain the same: -->
@foreach($product as $key => $item)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item['supplier']['name'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item['unit']['name'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item['category']['name'] }}</td>
      <td>
        <!-- Link to download the QR code image -->
        <a href="{{ DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($item->product_code, 'QRCODE') }}" download="{{ $item->product_code }}">
          <!-- QR code image -->
          <img src="{{ DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($item->product_code, 'QRCODE') }}" alt="QR Code" width="100" height="100" />
          <br>p - {{ $item -> product_code }}
        </a>
      </td>

*/
```

**2) or you can store both code and file path in your db**

> ***but for this you need to add a new field on your db table***

```
public function ProductStore(Request $request){
  
  // Generate the product code
  $product_code = uniqid();

  
  // Generate PNG path for the QR code                              
  $qrCodePath = DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($product_code, 'QRCODE');
  

  Product::insert([

    //insert data into product table
    'name' => $request->name,
    'supplier_id' => $request->supplier_id,
    'unit_id' => $request->unit_id,
    'category_id' => $request->category_id,
    'quantity' => '0',
    'product_code' => $product_code,  // SAVE CODE 
    'qr_path' => $qrCodePath,  // SAVE QR PATH 
    'created_by' => Auth::user()->id,
    'created_at' => Carbon::now(), 
  ]);

      
  $notification = array(
    'message' => 'Product Inserted Successfully', 
    'alert-type' => 'success'
  );

  return redirect()->route('product.all')->with($notification); 

} // End Method
```

and a change to your view is required too:

```
@foreach($product as $key => $item)
  <tr>
      <td>{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item['supplier']['name'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item['unit']['name'] }}</td>
      <td>{{ $item['category']['name'] }}</td>
      <td>
        <!-- Link to download the QR code image -->
        <a href="{{ $item -> qr_path }}" download="{{ $item->product_code }}">
          <!-- QR code image -->
          <img src="{{ $item -> qr_path }}" alt="QR Code" width="100" height="100" />
          <br>p - {{ $item -> product_code }}
        </a>
      </td>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works! The qrcode images will directly store in 'public' folder. May I ask what if I want to store the qrcode images to another folder inside the 'public' folder?